# System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code ERROR please help

Tags: c#-2.0

I am busy with an e-commerce web application using visual studio 2005 and IIS 7

I got this error

System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code

Message="The type initializer for 'ShopConfiguration' threw an exception."

Source="App_Code.r-ihwy-d"

TypeName="ShopConfiguration"

StackTrace:

```
   at ShopConfiguration.get_DbProviderName()

   at GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Beadafrican\App_Code\GenericDataAccess.cs:line 63

   at CatalogAccess.GetDepartments() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Beadafrican\App_Code\CatalogAccess.cs:line 28

   at UserControls_DepartmentsList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Beadafrican\UserControls\DepartmentsList.ascx.cs:line 22

   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

If I look at the code it refers to I dont see what is wrong? Here is the code if anyone can please assist it would be great!

GenericDataAccess.cs:

public static class GenericDataAccess
{
    //static constructor
    static GenericDataAccess()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

```
//execute a command and returns the result as a DataTable Object
public static DataTable ExecuteSelectCommand(DbCommand command)
{
    //The DataTable to be returned
    DataTable table;

    //Execute the command making sure the connection gets closed in the end
    try
    {
        //open the data connection
        command.Connection.Open();

        //Execute the command and save the results in a DataTable
        DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);

        //Close the reader
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.LogError(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close the connection
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
    return table;
}

//creates and prepares a new DbCommand object on a new connection
public static DbCommand CreateCommand()
{
    //Obtain the database provider name
    string dataProviderName = ShopConfiguration.DbProviderName;

    //Obtain the database connection string
    string connectionString = ShopConfiguration.DbConnectionString;

    //Create a new data provider factory
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dataProviderName);

    //Obtain a database specific connection object
    DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();

    //Set the connection string
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    //Create a database specific command object
    DbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();

    //Set the command type to stored procedure
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Return the initialised command object
    return comm;
}
```

CatalogAccess.cs

public static class CatalogAccess
{
    static CatalogAccess()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

```
//Retrieve the list of departments
public static DataTable GetDepartments()
{
    //get configured DbCommand object
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();

    //set the stored procedure name
    comm.CommandText = "GetDepartments";

    //execute the stored procedure and return the results
    return GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(comm);


}
```

}

DepartementList.ascx.cs

public partial class UserControls_DepartmentsList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // Load department details into the DataList
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // don't reload data during postbacks

```
   {
        // CatalogAccess.GetDepartments returns a DataTable object containing
        // department data, which is read in the ItemTemplate of the DataList
        list.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetDepartments();
        // Needed to bind the data bound controls to the data source
        list.DataBind();

    }
}
```

}

the ShopConfiguration class

{
    //Caches the connection string
    private readonly static string dbConnectionString;

```
//Caches the data provider name
private  readonly
```

static string dbProviderName;

```
//stores the number of products per page
private readonly static int productsPerPage;

//Stores the product description length for product lits
private readonly static int productDescriptionLenght;

//Store the name of your shop
private readonly static string siteName;

//Initialize various proeprties in the constructor
static ShopConfiguration()
{
    dbConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
    dbProviderName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ProviderName;
    productsPerPage = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsPerPage"]);
    productDescriptionLenght = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductDescriptionLenght"]);
    siteName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteName"];

}

//Returns the connection string for BeadAfrican database
public static string DbConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return dbConnectionString;
    }
}


//Returns the data provider name
public static string DbProviderName
{
    get
    {
        return dbProviderName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my connection string - maybe I am missing something? <connectionStrings> <remove name="LocalSqlServer" /> <add connectionString="Server=NATASJA-PC;Database=kates;Integrated Security=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 6):

I am quite sure that the `TypeInitializationException` that is thrown has another exception assigned to its `InnerException` property. If you examine that exception, I think you will find the real cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have specified an invalid setting for DbProviderName so internal checking code reports this exception. You'd better review the connection string settings.

Comment: This is my connection string - maybe I am missing something?
 <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        <add connectionString="Server=NATASJA-PC;Database=kates;Integrated Security=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>